# Avoiding the limits of yfinance with time.sleep

Tags: python, pandas-datareader, yfinance

Big newbie here.  I'm using pandas_datareader and yfinance to create an excel workbook with many stocks in it, but recently I have been getting more and more "failed to read symbol" errors, for stocks that definitely still exist.  Usually I can just run the code again and it'll work, but the problem seems to slowly be getting worse.  I've heard it suggested that maybe yahoo doesn't like to get that many requests at once, and perhaps a time.sleep method could be the solution.

But I'm enough of a beginner that I just don't know how to write that code.  Here's my code below; I want the exact same thing just with the delay, I guess between each stock.

```
import pandas_datareader as web
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

start = datetime(2020,9,1)
end = datetime(2021,12,31)
stock = [ 'ACHC',   'ACIW', [many more stocks listed here cut for simplicity], 'TECH',  'SAM']
 


df = web.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo', start, end)
df.to_excel(f'excelfilename.xlsx')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can put `time.sleep(seconds)` in the loop process. `import time;for s in stock:;df=...;time.sleep(seconds)`

Comment: well, that runs fine, but the original issue seems to still be happening.  Any idea why the above code, even with a time.sleep method, would be giving me a "SymbolWarning: Failed to read symbol" error on every single stock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also tried to run your code. I don't know why, but it gives me an error, so I installed the yahoo finance library and fixed the code. I created an empty data frame and added each stock to it.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

start = datetime(2020,9,1)
end = datetime(2021,12,31)
stocks= ['ACHC','ACIW','TECH','SAM']

dfs = pd.DataFrame()
for stock in stocks:
    print(stock)
    df = yf.download(stock, start, end)
    df['stock'] = stock
    dfs = dfs.append(df, ignore_index=True)
dfs.to_excel(f'excelfilename.xlsx')

dfs.head()
```

|  | Open | High | Low | Close | Adj Close | Volume | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 31.13 | 31.42 | 30.6 | 30.91 | 30.91 | 385700 | ACHC |
| 1 | 29.73 | 30.99 | 29.73 | 30.57 | 30.57 | 226500 | ACHC |
| 2 | 30.76 | 31.2 | 30.41 | 31.12 | 31.12 | 379300 | ACHC |
| 3 | 31.15 | 31.5 | 29.92 | 30.18 | 30.18 | 411200 | ACHC |
| 4 | 30.7 | 30.82 | 29.2 | 29.81 | 29.81 | 459500 | ACHC |

**EDIT:**
If you want to arrange them horizontally by stock, get the stocks one at a time in a list and change the level of the hierarchical index by deleting unnecessary columns. Then convert the hierarchical index name to a single line and rename the columns. After that, reorder the columns.

```
df = yf.download(stocks, start, end)
df.drop(['Adj Close',], axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.swaplevel(1, 0, axis=1)
df.columns = ["_".join(a) for a in df.columns.to_flat_index()]
df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
```

| Date | ACHC_Close | ACHC_High | ACHC_Low | ACHC_Open | ACHC_Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-08-31 00:00:00 | 30.91 | 31.42 | 30.6 | 31.13 | 385700 |
| 2020-09-01 00:00:00 | 30.57 | 30.99 | 29.73 | 29.73 | 226500 |
| 2020-09-02 00:00:00 | 31.12 | 31.2 | 30.41 | 30.76 | 379300 |
| 2020-09-03 00:00:00 | 30.18 | 31.5 | 29.92 | 31.15 | 411200 |
| 2020-09-04 00:00:00 | 29.81 | 30.82 | 29.2 | 30.7 | 459500 |

Comment: yahoo finance is also an easy way to get transaction data and financial information. The library can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/). If my answer was helpful to you, please accept it as a correct answer.

Comment: Hey, that's great!  It works!  One more tweak, and again, newbie here, but: is it possible to a) only keep some of the columns (specifically, not have the Adj Close and "stock" columns) and b) have each stock start a new set of columns?  i.e., columns A, B, C, D, and E correspond to ACHC, then columns F, G, H, I, and J correspond to ACIW, etc?

Comment: Okay, one last question.  Is it possible to leave the stocks in the order I've got them listed, i.e., not re-sort alphabetically by ticker symbol?  Even if it meant all of the closing prices are together, THEN all the open prices, etc.  Much appreciated!  This is a big help!

Comment: I sort by the end of the code I added. If you don't do that, it will be sorted by price type.

Comment: Right, that puts them into alphabetical order by ticker symbol.  I'm saying, if I wanted QQQ, then ABC, then XYZ, and leave them in that order (rather than have it re-sorted to ABC, QQQ, and XYZ), is there any way to do that?

Comment: For the method added in the edit, the retrieved results will be in alphabetical order of the stocks.

Comment: Okay, I think I can work with that then.  Thanks so much!  This has been a lifesaver.